# Read compressed CSV (gzip) file from AWS S3 into Panda data frame in Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to read a large compressed CSV file from AWS S3 and convert it to a Panda data frame in Sagemaker. Is there any direct and clean approach to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [AWS Wrangler](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/2.4.0-docs/index.html) library to do so, easily

It supports GZIP compression, and will read the CSV directly into a Pandas dataframe

(pip install awswranger)

```
import awswrangler as wr

df = wr.s3.read_csv(path="s3://bucket/path/to/my.csv.gzip")
```